# Can't handle async requests

Tags: jquery, typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm trying to create bootstrap tagsinput with remote source (get tags from server).When I use synchronous request - it works great, but the screen freezes for some time after each letter pressed, waiting for AJAX to complete. And the less internet connection speed user has, the more screen freezes.

I've tried to use documentation https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ but they use Bloodhound there and I've tried for several hours to handle it but no chance. So I just decided to use typeaheadjs instead.

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
obj.tagsinput({
    tagClass: function (item) {
        return 'cf-tag-' + item.color;
    },
    itemValue: 'id',
    itemText: 'name',
    typeaheadjs: function(query, process = false) {
        tagsFinal = [];

        $.ajax({
                url: tagsInputArgs.ajaxUrl,
                async: false,
                data: {
                        'action': 'get_budget_tags',
                        'security': tagsInputArgs.security,
                        'budget_id': $('.budget_id').val(),
                        'query': query
                },
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                        tagsFinal = data;
                        if (process)
                                process(data);
                }
        });

        //process(tagsFinal);

        return tagsFinal;
    }
});
```

The JSON I get from the server is :

```
[
    {
        "id":"75",
        "budget_id":"91",
        "name":"electronic",
         "color":"cyan"
    }
]
```

It works while async is set to false. If I invert this, no matter how much and where I process the data - no autocomplete whatsoever. I've tried to use $.get(), but no results.

The expected result is to get the same autocomplete tags input, but without freezing the screen(perhaps the autocomplete will appear with some delay, but it still would be better).

Comment: Please show the network stuff going on in the developers console aswell as the warnings/errors from the console.

Comment: if you set  `aysnc: true` it will always return an empty array. for you to get the data add  a callback funtion.